# Creating a custom Add-in for Excel 2016 and it is not available from the My Add-In menu

Tags: excel, add-in

I have created an Excel add-in following the instructions from https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/build-your-first-excel-add-in.  Everything went fine following along with the instructions and then I copied the solution out to a network share and then copied the manifest file to a different network share.

Then I tried following the instructions in the "Try it out" section of the page with adding the network location of the manifest file to into the Trusted Add-On Catalogs.  Then after restarting Excel and going into the My Add-Ins button I see the Shared Folder tab on the screen, but I do not see the custom add-in, so I can't select it.  Does anyone know what I'm missing.

My manifest file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
      <Id>D38C7DFE-AC71-4C20-B477-BD8508058D95</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sample Excel Add-In" />
      <Description DefaultValue="Sample Excel Add-In"/>
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="Workbook" />
      </Capabilities>
      <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="\\pathtowheresolutionwas copied\ExcelAddInTest\Home.html" />
      </DefaultSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    </OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was I followed along with the instructions in the document, but there is one part that is not really correct.  It has you copy the Website out to a network share, but that can't be copied out to a network share it needs to be published to a website that is running https.